# .submit() called through javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I was having trouble determining what was cause my form to not submit when I called

```
$('#form').submit();
```

through javascript (but submitted fine when I clicked on the submit button).  So I add this piece of code for testing:

```
$('#form').live('submit', function()
{
    alert('submitting form');
    return true;
});
```

Now when I click the submit button, the alert displays and then the form submits.  When I call:

```
$('#form').submit();
```

through javascript, the alert displays however the form does not submit.  Now I am pulling the form through ajax onto a modal window so not sure if that has anything to do with it.  Anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `submit` event is not supported with the `live` function.

From the jQuery API:

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following
>   JavaScript events (in addition to
>   custom events) could be bound with
>   .live(): **click, dblclick, keydown,
>   keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove,
>   mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup**. As
>   of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method
>   supports custom events as well as all
>   JavaScript events. As of jQuery 1.4.1
>   even focus and blur work with live
>   (mapping to the more appropriate,
>   bubbling, events focusin and
>   focusout). As of jQuery 1.4.1 the
>   hover event can be specified (mapping
>   to "mouseenter mouseleave").

Comment: I tried switching the submit button input type to button instead of submit and made the .live() event a click on that button.  The ajax request in the .live event runs fine, it still does not execute the form.submit() method when called through javascript in that click event.

Comment: Did you try what I put in my answer. Would have thought that would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling submit() on the HTMLFormElement object:

```
$("#form")[0].submit();
```

Same results?

Comment: Would do the same as $("#form").submit(); as id's can only be used once. Unless you meant  $("form")[0].submit();

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").trigger('submit');
```

???